# In my blogging website i want to delete a user and all its associated blogs and comments

Tags: python, django

I deleted a user, then all the associated blogs were also deleted but the associated comments are not deleted. Why comments model is indirectly related to User model using foreign key.
Can anyone give me the answer

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class blogpost(models.Model):
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=122,null=True,blank=False)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False)
    post=models.TextField()
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True )


    def __str__(self):
        return ' (' +str(self.created_by)+') Title- '+self.title
    
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-date']


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(blogpost ,related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' %(self.post.title, self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering=['-date_added']
```

```
views.py

def comment_view(request, pk):
    if request.method=='POST' and 'comment_button' in request.POST:
        
        body=request.POST.get('comment_text')

        post=blogpost.objects.get(pk=pk)
        obj=CommentModel(body=body)
        obj.name=request.user
        obj.post=post
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detaildata',args=[str(pk)]))
```

Comment: This `name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)` is not a foreign key...

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have set `on_delete=models.CASCADE` in models, which is great.

You **just have to delete the user**, and belonging blogpost (and similarly so the comment) will get deleted on its own.

You can manually delete the user from *Django Admin Panel* or delete it from the shell. Here are the steps

```
$ python manage.py shell
...
$ User.objects.filter(id=1).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you put **on_delete** on **models.CASCADE**, this will cause comments to be deleted if a user is removed.

You have two options:

1. Do this through the admin panel.
2. Enter into django shell using `python manage.py shell` and do so using `User.objects.filter(id=1).delete ()`